# FermionSpinSum: encountered a fatal problem and must abort the computation

Tags: warning-messages

While running my teacher example using Feyncalc and FeynArts 3.10, I encounter this warning from Mathematica

```
In[67]:= MsLLc=ComplexConjugate[MsLL]/.{\[Mu]-> \[Mu]1}
During evaluation of In[67]:= FermionSpinSum::failmsg: Error! FermionSpinSum encountered a fatal problem and must abort the computation. The problem reads: The input contains Spinor objects with incorrect syntax.
Out[67]= $Aborted
```

How can I fix this error?
When extracting FeynArts 3.10.tar, I receive this message:

[image]

Is it related to a problem in Mathematica?

Thank you.

**Edit**

Here is the Mathematica code:

```
szLL = (-I*gez*Cgzp)/(qsqs - mz*mz)*
   Contract[
    Spinor[p2, me].DiracMatrix[
      6].DiracMatrix[\[Sigma]].(ve - ae*DiracMatrix[5]).DiracMatrix[
      7].Spinor[p1, 
      me].(MetricTensor[\[Sigma], \[Beta]] - 
       FourVector[qs, \[Sigma]].FourVector[qs, \[Beta]]/(
       mz*mz)).(MetricTensor[\[Mu], \[Beta]].Pair[Momentum[qs], 
         Momentum[k1]] - 
       FourVector[qs, \[Mu]].FourVector[k1, \[Beta]])];
sgLL = (-I*e*Cggp)/qsqs*
   Contract[
    Spinor[p2, me].DiracMatrix[6].DiracMatrix[\[Sigma]].DiracMatrix[
      7].Spinor[p1, 
      me].MetricTensor[\[Sigma], \[Beta]].(MetricTensor[\[Mu], \
\[Beta]].Pair[Momentum[qs], Momentum[k1]] - 
       FourVector[qs, \[Mu]].FourVector[k1, \[Beta]])];
MsLL = szLL + sgLL;
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: The error message says “The input contains Spinor objects with incorrect syntax.” What is the input `MsLL`?

Comment: I edited the post, could you please check for me again? Thanks a lot @Ghoster

Comment: The error messages you're getting suggest you're having trouble accessing files. This is more an OS level problem, rather than a Mathematica/FeynCalc problem. It appears that you're having trouble unpacking the file you downloaded.

Comment: The question is confusing because it discusses unrelated problems (installation vs. runtime). You haven’t shown any output other than the fatal runtime error. Please show output for szLL, sgLL, and MsLL. I’m skeptical that the error is from the call to ComplexConjugate.

Comment: I’m trying to help but I’m not that familiar with Feyncalc. I’m used to Dirac gamma matrices having an index that runs from 0 to 3. So what is DiracMatrix[7], for example? Are you working in higher dimensions? What is ve? If it’s not a matrix, you can’t add it to a Dirac matrix. (Or does Feyncalc implicitly multiply it by the identity matrix?)

Comment: Thank all of you guys very much for trying to help with my problem. After a really long time taking my computer to the computer store and getting it done, I realized the problem was YES - my failure to unpack the FeynCalc package. Hence I told the store owner to try different versions of FeynCalc available online, but it also did not work.

Comment: I had to ask my teacher for help, and my teacher asked her teacher to solve this for me. Finally, he sent me an alternative file of FeynCalc that I didn't know where he got from. And everything was solved just yesterday. Sorry for taking so long to reply to all your comments. I will show how to solve this problem in the answer in case others need it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar error *"The input contains Spinor objects with incorrect syntax"*.

I found in the [documentation of Spinor](https://feyncalc.github.io/FeynCalcBook/ref/Spinor.html) that it is expressed as `Spinor[Momentum[p], m]`. Many old tutorials (like the one I was following) had `Spinor[p,m]` to describe the spinor; you are also writing spinors like that in your code. Specifying p as momentum as in `Spinor[Momentum[p], m]` (following the documentation examples) solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After getting helps from many people, I can solve my problem in this way:

Firstly, you need to download this file called FeynCalc online. If the file online does not work, please feel free to contact me, I will immediately send you the file FeynCalc that works for me.
Using

> %appdata%

then get access to Roaming, and find Mathematica.
In Mathematica, find Applications. Add the file FeynCalc to it.
Those are all the steps you need to do.